# Firma certificado digital en mensaje AXIS2 SOAP

Tags: java, soap

No consigo firmar con certificado digital un mensaje AXIS2.

Os explico donde estamos:

1.- Tenemos las clases generadas a partir del servicio SOAP con la herramienta wsdl2java. Lo que vienen llamando el “stub”.

2.- El servicio SOAP está en https pero también tenemos cargado el certificado correspondiente dentro del archivo de certificados “cacerts” que usa java.

3.- A través de todas las clases del “stub” ya creamos peticiones y recibimos respuesta del servicio SOAP.

Ahora, ciertas peticiones que necesitamos deben ir “firmadas” con el certificado digital de la empresa.

No encontramos documentación o ejemplos de código que funcionen de cómo se firmaría el mensaje.

¿Alguién con experiencia que nos oriente en el código a utilizar?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de firma es necesaria? (XML tiene varios formatos de firma). Si no lo sabéis, ¿tenéis algún ejemplo  de un XML firmado?

Comment: Supongo que ya lo habrás solucionado, sino mira esto: https://unbeagleyyo.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/firmar-webservices-axis-con-wss4j-y-certificados-x509/ y esto: http://www.dipalme.org/Servicios/Anexos/Anexos.nsf/porclasificador/73E873C6E7B7299BC12576310038B43A/%24File/MAP-TI-20-1178-%40Firma-Global-XMLSOAP-MAN.pdf a mi me ha servido para firmar digitalmente

Comment: Yo estoy con el mismo problema, he conseguido generar las cabeceras adecuadas, pero las librerías para cifrar crypto XML no "son compatibles" con el SOAP de axis2 ya que son distintos objetos. Miraré lo que pone Kepa, pero de momento no encuentro solución ni documentación. Si lo resuelvo, aunque sea cutre, pondré la respuesta.